# Making a triangle polygon in an applet

Tags: java, applet

```
        int size = RNG.randomNum(0, ((1000/numOfShapes)*10));
        int xOrigin = RNG.randomNum(0, 2000);
        int yOrigin = RNG.randomNum(0, 1080);

        int[] xPoints = null;
        int[] yPoints = null;
        Polygon p = new Polygon(xPoints, yPoints,3);
        //g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(xOrigin, yOrigin, xOrigin+size, yOrigin+size));
        //g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(xOrigin+size, yOrigin+size, xOrigin + size, yOrigin));
        //g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(xOrigin, yOrigin, xOrigin+size, yOrigin));
        g2.fillPolygon(p);
```

The 3 times g2.draw is used makes me a nice right triangle, but I want it to be filled with a color. How should I go forth turning those points into a triangle polygon so it can be filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int xpoints[] = {xOrigin, xOrigin+size, xOrigin + size};
    int ypoints[] = {yOrigin , yOrigin+size, yOrigin};

    g2.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, 3);
```